# Dynamic directive in Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-directives

Is it possible to use dynamic directives? I want to use `v-show` or `v-if` based on props.

E.g. `<div :[directiveType]="isActive"></div>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, but you can easily use both with common condition. Only tricky part is you want true by default.

```
<div 
    v-if="isActive || directiveType !== 'if'"
    v-show="isActive || directiveType !== 'show'"
>
```